# How can I define a variable inside a function to be called by an event

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, static-variables

How can I set a function variable so can I call outside of the context, like this example

```
function testSet(elmA,elmB) {
    elmA.onclick = function() {
        elmB.value = "ok";
    };
}

testSet(document.getElementById('a'),document.getElementById('b'));
```

this doesn't work because when the `onclick` event is called it is called probably from `window` and `elmB` is undefined.

How can I get this working without flooding the global-scope like `window.elmB = elmB;`?

I'm having this issue with events and callbacks.

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/TR7ZH/

Comment: Couldn't you just use `Function.bind` to bind the context-scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elmB` is not `undefined`. Your code works fine, because JavaScript has closures, i.e. variables retain their value for nested functions. Perhaps you're not calling it *after* the elements exist - say, at the bottom of the page, or in `onload`?

Comment: thanks for the answer, the issue was a typo, trying to figure this out for and hour, I though this doesn't work. sorry for that, I'm in trouble with code tracking...

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just make the variable global and access ir whenever you want to?
Like this:

```
var globalElmB = something;

function testSet(elmA,elmB){
    globalElmb = elmB;
    elmA.onclick=function(){

        globalElmb.value="ok";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of even making a function if it only works properly once, further calls would overwrite the global and the previous ones would stop working. The OP's code works fine without this drawback even.

Comment: sometimes you need this behavior, if you have multiple elements "pointing" to some "target", if you forward to another element, you should expect to the "old target" stop to respond. sorry if this, or the example sounded too abstract